# Calculate elevation profile for a line from dem data

Tags: postgis, arcobjects, dem, elevation, profile

We are trying to implement a service which takes a line geometry as its input and calculates elevation profile along that line from dem data (img format).

How could we achieve this using postgis or arcgis stack?

Comment: Please decide whether you are trying to do this using PostGIS or ArcGIS and then, rather than just describing what you want to do in a single sentence, can you tell us precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Add Surface Information (3d) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000016000000, be sure to densify the line first - two point lines will work but the result isn't very useful, without any code I cannot advise on how to implement this. The word 'service' seems to indicate you want this to happen on a web page, but again without any code I can't be sure.